# Flutter: Schedule audio events for background execution

Tags: audio, mobile, dart, flutter, background-process

I am implementing an app in Flutter, for which I need to schedule (audio) events in advance. Only after one event is completed I can schedule the next, since the duration of the event might not be known before. Each audio event is a notification sound for the user, thus scheduling and audio playback should both work while the app has no focus or the phone is locked.

I currently fail to implement these specifications and I guess I'm just not thinking the right way about it for the moment. Since I started to learn Flutter recently, there could also be just some simple misunderstandings from my part. Let me summarize what I know about background execution & native code in Flutter, please correct anything wrong with these statements:

- When the App looses focus (or the phone gets locked) code execution stops.
- However, inside the "primary" Dart-code, I can spawn an isolate which will run even with the phone locked or without focus on the app.
- Different isolates share no memory whatsoever; they communicate via ports.
- There a spawned isolate does not know anything about the flutter ecosystem, therefore it is not possible to use flutter plugins.
- For the same reasons I cannot use `MethodChannels` as well to communicate with platform code from an isolate.

---

From this I conclude:

- The event should be scheduled from a seperate Dart-isolate, so that locking the phone won't halt scheduling.
- This isolate won't be able to play any audio file by itself, and won't be able to communicate with platform code.
- Thus, it needs to communicate with the primary isolate, which can play audio. However, without the app open, the code won't respond.
- Consequently, this approach cannot work?

Right now, I am stuck at this point and don't know how to continue. I guess one option could be to directly call java/swift code for the respective native platforms and handle scheduling and audio there. Yet, I hope that I just don't see a simpler option right now.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @PaulSumpner No, but I also haven't tuched Flutter in the past year :'D The last time I used it there were promising packages in development for this, but I don't know the current situation